# Rescale the sum of a finite number of elements while preserving the maximum

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose there are real $a_i$ such that $\sum_i^N a_i = A$. I'm looking for a function $f(a_i)$ such that $\begin{equation}
\sum_i^N f(a_i)=B \tag{I}\end{equation}$ and at the same time
$\max (f(a_i)) = \max (a_i). \tag{II}$

Let us assume that $a_i \geq 0$ and require $\max (a_i) < B < N \cdot \max (a_i)$. Essentially I need to re-scale the elements to sum to B while at the same time keep the maximum element.
As a plan b one could relax (II) such that $\max (f(a_i)) \leq \max (a_i)$. Any ideas?

PS: The flat solution $f(a_i)=B/N$ is *not* what I'm looking for as I'm interested in preserving the variability of the original series as much as possible.

Edit: In the original question I was looking for $f$ as a multiplicative factor (as in  $\sum a_i \cdot f(a_i)$). This has been modified to allow for more solutions.

Comment: Must $f$ be an explicit formula, or can it be the solution of an optimization problem?

Comment: I'd prefer an explicit solution. On the other hand, if such a solution is too difficult to find I might as well resort to the solution of an optimization problem.

Answer (score 1):

Given $(a_1,\dots,a_N)$ and $B$ with $\sum_i a_i = A$, you want to find $(b_1,\dots,b_N)$ with $\sum_i b_i = B$ and $a_i$ "close" to $b_i$.

Without the restriction on the max (and assuming $A \not= 0$), a simple approach would be to take $b_i = B a_i / A$ for all $i$.

With the restriction $b_i \le \max_j a_j$, you could solve a least squares problem: minimize $\sum_i (a_i - b_i)^2$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_i b_i &= B \\
0 \le b_i &\le \max_j a_j &&\text{for all $i$} \\
\end{align}